# How to disable shared folders passowrd prompt on window & Linux

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

I'm using windows xp, vista, server 2008 R2, ubuntu-linux 9.10, 9.04, 8.10 desktop editions. I shared some folders/directories in windows and in ubuntu machines. Normally for the first time it's prompted for the password when tried to access the shared folders on either of the machine and again they prompt for the password when the system is rebooted. Recently I've created a batch and sh script which copies from the shared folders from windows to ubuntu and vice-versa. But the scripts cannot automate the password prompt and I'm wondering if I could disable the password prompt of the shared folders on windows and as well as on ubuntu machines so that my script runs smoothly. I don't know if it's possible or not but want to confirm posting here and if it is then nothing but saying need help...!. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible.

Have a look at these two links for the answer. First you will want to add the Ubuntu machine to Active Directory (I assume you are using it.) And on the Ubuntu box you can mount Windows shares on boot up. Actually, a third link just in case you need it to set up shares on the Ubuntu box. Lastly, you might want to look into command line options for WinSCP or installing Cygwin on the Windows box.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202605